# Scrapy - Exclude Unwanted URLs (Like Comments)

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to crawl websites to get all pages, but my current code rules are still allowing me to get unwanted URLs such as a comment links like "http://www.example.com/some-article/comment-page-1" in addition to the post's main URL. What can I add to rules to exclude these unwanted items? Here is my current code:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.item import Item

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'crawltest'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'/\d+']), follow=True), Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'\d+']), callback='parse_item')]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        #do something
```

Answer (score 2):

[`SgmlLinkExtractor`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#sgmllinkextractor) has an optional argument called `deny`, This will only match the rule if allow regex is true and deny regex is false

example from [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example):

```
rules = (
        # Extract links matching 'category.php' (but not matching 'subsection.php')
        # and follow links from them (since no callback means follow=True by default).
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('category\.php', ), deny=('subsection\.php', ))),

        # Extract links matching 'item.php' and parse them with the spider's method parse_item
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('item\.php', )), callback='parse_item'),
    )
```

Perhaps you could check that the url does not contain the word `comment`?

Comment: This works. But how about using regular expression to achieve the same? For example, constraining no `/` to follow  `some-article` so that `http://www.example.com/some-article/comment-page-1` is invalid. I tried `allow=r"some-article[^/]?"` but doesn't work. Any ideas?